# Powershell Regex Phone Validation

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

Wanting to put a check into a new hire creation script that checks the format of numbers to follow a specific format.

Everything is good when the number comes from the csv, but wanting to add a feature where a user can input the correct number incase the csv was entered incorrectly. For some reason the read-host input doesn't match the regex validation even regardless if pasted or typed in.

```
telepattern = "^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$" 
$telephone = "777 7755"

if ($telephone -match $telepattern) {
Write-Host "Phone number is valid."
 } else {
     Do {
        Write-Host "Error: Phone number does not match the expected format (e.g., (808) 973-6391)."
        $telephone = Read-Host "Re-enter the 10 digit number of $fullname" 
        } until ($Telephone -match '$telepattern')       
}
```

Comment: typo: `until ($Telephone -match '$telepattern')` => `until ($Telephone -match $telepattern)`. Variable can't expand in single quotes.